# Equivalent matlab code to maths formula (covariance matrix for eigenfaces algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, covariance

[image]

I'm developing the eigenfaces algorithm for face recognition. Having subtracted the mean from the training images I now have the matrix A with the centered images.

Now I'm not sure whether the matlab code AxA' is equivalent the whole first line shown in the image above or just the ΣΦnΦn' part.

So what I'm asking is do I still need to divide AxA' by M (training set size) or is it part of the matrix multiplication carried out by Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that only the ΣΦnΦn' part is equivalent to AxA' so division by M is ALSO required. I have found the way to do the sum on paper and I tried a simple 2x2 matrix (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621036/how-sum-work-vectors-and-matrices).

For a matrix Q = [1 2 ; 3 4] the transpose Q' = [1 3 ; 2 4]. On paper ΣQnQn' = [5 11 ; 11 25] and in Matlab QxQ' = [5 11 ; 11 25]. This shows that the 1/M part of the formula is not done by Matlab and I need to do it separately.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the notation used in this paper and/or in Matlab. From a strictly mathematical point of view, the two must be equal.

In a general terms, if you have subtracted the mean value, the next step is to evaluate the covariance matrix (have a look at `cov()` in Matlab) and then from such matrix you should extract eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: this particular paper is the Turk and Pentland "Eigenfaces for recognition" but it seems to be the same notation in all papers I have read. Yes I was trying to find the mathematical expansion of the ΣΦnΦn' part so I can compare the resulting matrix for a simple example to the result given by Matlab but I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: I've been looking at the paper and yes, the two expressions are equivalent. You can use one or the other: you can concatenate all the Φ together and perform A*A' or perform the sum of all the Φ and divide by M.

Comment: okay thanks! i have just found some math videos on youtube on matrix multiplication, will just verify it :)

Comment: In a Matlab-ian way, let's say `X` is your training set where each column is an image. From section "Calculating Eigenfaces" is pretty clear that such images must be reshaped as a column vector. Concatenating such column vectors will lead to the matrix `X`. Next step is to subtract the mean value (Ψ, in the paper) from all the images (columns): so you need to evaluate the mean of each row (column vector) and subtract such value from every column. Now you want to use `cov()` on such matrix (remember to transpose the matrix as input in `cov()`!) and the evaluate the eigenvalues/vectors

Comment: turns out that only the ΣΦnΦn' part is equivalent to AxA' so division by M is ALSO required. I have found the way to do the sum on paper and I tried a simple 2x2 matrix (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621036/how-sum-work-vectors-and-matrices). For a matrix Q = [1 2 ; 3 4] the transpose Q' = [1 3 ; 2 4]. On paper ΣQnQn' = [5 11 ; 11 25] and in Matlab QxQ' = [5 11 ; 11 25]. This shows that the 1/M part of the formula is not done by Matlab and I need to do it separately. Correct me if I have made any mistake :)

Comment: Yes indeed, I've been further checking the maths. There's an error in the paper. The second equation should have 1/M as well given the definition of A included in the paper itself.